# transfer data from one dimensional array in two-dimensional array java

Tags: java, arrays

Assume I have one dimensional `array`

```
int[] arr = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

and I need transfer all data from this `arr` in two-dimensional `array`

```
 int[][]array = new int[2][1];
```

bellow code:

```
for (int i = 0; i <array.length ; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <array[j].length ; j++) {
        array[i][j] = arr[i];
    }
}
```

return result:

```
[[1], [2]]
```

I need:

```
[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
```

How to achieve it?

Comment: What keeps you from modifying the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 2d array is too small. To get the output you want, it needs to have a shape of 2 by 3.

```
int[][] array = new int[2][3];
```

You will also need to change the loop that builds the array. It has to keep track of the index for the original array separately from the indices of the 2d array.

```
int indexForArr = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <array.length ; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <array[j].length ; j++) {
        array[i][j] = arr[indexForArr];
        indexForArr = indexForArr + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 with int[][] array = new int[2][3];

Comment: the loop also needs to be changed - see update. Can't believe I missed that